# Calculate the average of the top 80% of values in a column Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I get the top 80% of an unsorted column of values that includes 0s?

```
values
1
1
0.3333333333
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
```

If the top 80% of values to average is not a rational number, I need it to average both above and below the rational number:

(e.g. 11 values * 0.8 = 8.8 values to consider, so it should average the top 8 and the top 9 values)

so far I've this: `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A12,">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A12,80%))`

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)*80%)),
 {AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(A1:A)*80%)));
  AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A1:A)*80%)))})
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

If by 'top 80%' you mean the largest 80%, I would use sortn:

```
=average(sortn(A:A,rounddown(count(A:A)*0.8),,1,false))
```

and

```
=average(sortn(A:A,ROUNDUP(count(A:A)*0.8),,1,false))
```

[image]

The average of the top 8 numbers is 7.5 and the average of the top 9 numbers is 7.